# how to optimise component that useContext in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the question is simple but it probably has some answers that I'm still not aware of

How to optimise component, that use useContext ? Obviously this component will be rerendered every time context value changed(correct me if i'm wrong) and the same works for redux either(again correct me). I'm trying to crack this question to avoid pitfalls at interview.

I asked chat GPT and it answered me the following

```
import React, { useContext, memo } from 'react';

const MyComponent = memo(() => {
  const contextValue = useContext(MyContext);

});
```

But as far as I understand - that is not correct and won't affect rerendering.

What I think is that we can wrap in react memo components that are children of that component that use useContext, and when we use useContext we should be aware of the price we pay to use global state, that it will cause some redundant rerenders and we can just optimize children on such components to prevent rerender (if we need it);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer something so broadly described, so here's a concrete example:

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useState, useEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const defaultOverbroadContext = {
    a: "This string doesn't change",
    b: 0,
};
const OverbroadContext = createContext(defaultOverbroadContext);

const Example = React.memo(() => {
    console.log("Example render");
    const { a } = useContext(OverbroadContext);
    return <div style={{border: "1px solid black"}}>This is the <code>Example</code> component, a = {a}</div>;
});

const App = () => {
    console.log("App render");
    const [a, setA] = useState(defaultOverbroadContext.a);
    const [b, setB] = useState(defaultOverbroadContext.b);
    const overbroadContext = useMemo(() => ({ a, b }), [a, b]);
    
    useEffect(() =>{
        // Update `b` every 800ms
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setB((b) => b + 1);
        }, 800);
        // Stop after 10s...
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        }, 10000);
        return () => {
            // ...or when unmounted
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <OverbroadContext.Provider value={overbroadContext}>
            <div>b = {b}</div>
            <Example />
        </OverbroadContext.Provider>
    );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

There, the `Example` component unnecessarily re-renders when the context's `b` property changes, because it only uses the `a` property. I think that's what you're talking about, and you're asking how to optimize the component.

I'd say it's not the component that needs optimization, it's the context. It's too broad. It should be split into a context for `a` and a context for `b`, and then `Example` should just use the `a` context; then it won't re-render when `b` changes:

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useState, useEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const aDefault = "This string doesn't change";
const AContext = createContext(aDefault);

const bDefault = 0;
const BContext = createContext(bDefault);

const Example = React.memo(() => {
    console.log("Example render");
    const a = useContext(AContext);
    return <div style={{border: "1px solid black"}}>This is the <code>Example</code> component, a = {a}</div>;
});

const App = () => {
    console.log("App render");
    const [a, setA] = useState(aDefault);
    const [b, setB] = useState(bDefault);
    
    useEffect(() =>{
        // Update `b` every 800ms
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setB((b) => b + 1);
        }, 800);
        // Stop after 10s...
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        }, 10000);
        return () => {
            // ...or when unmounted
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <AContext.Provider value={a}>
            <BContext.Provider value={b}>
                <div>b = {b}</div>
                <Example />
            </BContext.Provider>
        </AContext.Provider>
    );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

In the subset of cases where you can't fix it at the context level, you can split the component into two parts (I think this may be what you were alluding to in your final paragraph):

```
const ExampleOuter = React.memo(() => {
    console.log("ExampleOuter render");
    const { a } = useContext(OverbroadContext);
    return <ExampleInner a={a} />;
});

const ExampleInner = React.memo(({ a }) => {
    console.log("ExampleInner render");
    return <div style={{border: "1px solid black"}}>This is the <code>ExampleInner</code> component, a = {a}</div>;
});
```

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useState, useEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const defaultOverbroadContext = {
    a: "This string doesn't change",
    b: 0,
};
const OverbroadContext = createContext(defaultOverbroadContext);

const ExampleOuter = React.memo(() => {
    console.log("ExampleOuter render");
    const { a } = useContext(OverbroadContext);
    return <ExampleInner a={a} />;
});

const ExampleInner = React.memo(({ a }) => {
    console.log("ExampleInner render");
    return <div style={{border: "1px solid black"}}>This is the <code>ExampleInner</code> component, a = {a}</div>;
});

const App = () => {
    console.log("App render");
    const [a, setA] = useState(defaultOverbroadContext.a);
    const [b, setB] = useState(defaultOverbroadContext.b);
    const overbroadContext = useMemo(() => ({ a, b }), [a, b]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // Update `b` every 800ms
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            setB((b) => b + 1);
        }, 800);
        // Stop after 10s...
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        }, 10000);
        return () => {
            // ...or when unmounted
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <OverbroadContext.Provider value={overbroadContext}>
            <div>b = {b}</div>
            <ExampleOuter />
        </OverbroadContext.Provider>
    );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

*(That's a very basic, mostly-conceptual example. For instance, it doesn't handle forwarding refs.)*

When the context changes in a way that doesn't affect `a`, `ExampleOuter` re-renders, but `ExampleInner` doesn't because it doesn't use the context and is memoized on the thing that doesn't change.

But again: The need to do that suggests the context is too broad in the first place.